# Cycle through a list of agents gives an error

Tags: javascript, xpages, agent

I have this code on an action button that should just run through the Agents and disable all of the scheduled agents:

```
   var agentList:Array = database.getAgents();
   3: for (var n=0 ; n < agentList.length; ++n ){
   4:   var name:string = agentList[n];
   5:   dBar.info(name,"Agent Name ");
   6:   var ag:NotesAgent = database.getAgent(name);
   7:   dBar.info(ag.getName());
   8:   if (ag.isEnabled()){
   9:       dBar.info(ag.getName(),"Is Enabled ");
  10:       ag.isEnabled() = false;
  11:   }
  12: }
```

The problem is that when I run it I get this error:

Error while executing JavaScript action expression
Script interpreter error, line=6, col=38: [TypeError] Method NotesDatabase.getAgent(lotus.domino.local.Agent) not found, or illegal parameters

I know from the dBar that name is in fact the name of the first agent in the list and is a string. But it would appear that it is treating the name string as a lotus.domino.local.agent.

Am I missing something really obvious? I have Manager Access to the Database even set the max Internet access to Manager as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BillF: referring to your comments to @TimTripcony's answer:

a) LotusScript's language structure cannot be compared to what we have with SSJS: LS is a close relative to VisualBasic allowing read/write properties, whereas SSJS has a closer relationship to Java, where we usually have separate methods for reading and changing properties.

b) I think you are correct in doubting your approach of allowing the manipulation of a design element through http. A possible approach could be to write a server-side LS agent to perform your task which then could be triggered from your SSJS code. It might be necessary to use `sessionAsSigner` to be able to properly trigger the agent, and of course you need to make sure that only an Administrator may be able to do so.

Comment: Actually I have a fair bit of LS Libraries that I call and run from SSJS using run on server because the process needs to run with a high level of access and also the ability to delete a document. So your suggestion is probably the answer. I just hadn't put it together with this function.

Comment: I created an LS Agent that does this and I call it via runOnServer and it works great.

Answer (score 3):

`database.getAgents()` returns a list of *agents*, not a list of agent *names*. By coercing `name` to `string` you might be able to convince the debug toolbar to tell you it is a string, but it shouldn't be.

Try this:

```
var agentList = database.getAgents();
for (var n = 0; n < agentList.length; n++) {
    var eachAgent = agentList[n];
    if (eachAgent.isEnabled() {
        dBar.info(eachAgent.getName(), "Is Enabled");
        eachAgent.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Note in particular the substitution of `setEnabled()` in the last line of the `if`...

Comment: In the gelp it says that isEnabled is read-write but it is not. When I modify the JS to the above it fails on the eachAgent.setEnabled(false) with the error Script interpreter error, line=5, col=27: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesAgent.setEnabled(boolean) null - I have Manager right to the DB so I'm really confused now.

Comment: The `enabled` property is read-write: `isEnabled()` is a read, `setEnabled(boolean)` is a write. However, toggling the `enabled` property requires at least Designer access... by default, the maximum ACL level when accessing an app from a browser is Editor. Check the advanced section of the app's ACL to verify that the max level is at least Designer.

Comment: Wrote this in LS and it works isEnabled in LS is read/write :
Sub Initialize
 Dim session As New NotesSession
 Dim db As NotesDatabase
 Set db = session.CurrentDatabase
 If IsArray(db.Agents) Then
  ForAll a In db.Agents
   If a.trigger = 1 then
    If a.isEnabled Then
     a.isEnabled = false
     a.save
    End If
   End if
  End ForAll
 End If
 
End Sub

I needed to check the trigger property first to or it failed on a couple of agents in the list.

Comment: So I modified the JS code to this but it wont even execute:
var agents = database.getAgents().iterator();
while (agents.hasNext()) {
 var thisAgent:NotesAgent = agents.next();
 if (thisAgent.TRIGGER_SCHEDULED ){
  if (thisAgent.isEnabled()){
   thisAgent.setEnabled(false);
   thisAgent.save();
  }
 }
 thisAgent.recycle();
}

Comment: ps. I have manager rights to the DB and the Max internet is also manager. When I ran the LS agent of course I was running as a Notes client. I don't believe that it is good security to have the internet access set to Designer or Manager so not sure how to get around that part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In LotusScript language `Notesdatabase.Agents` returns an array of **NotesAgent objects**.

I never tried in SSJS to day, but SSJS Domino Designer Help has this to say for the `database.getAgents()` method (see *IBM Domino Designer XPages Reference > Domino > NotesDatabase (JavaScript)*):

> **Syntax**
>   getAgents() : java.util.Vector
>
> **Usage**
>   The elements of the return vector are of type NotesAgent

and in the example that follows a java iterator is used to loop through the list of agent objects returned (looks exactly like your task, really):

```
var agents = database.getAgents().iterator();
var list = "";
while (agents.hasNext()) {
    list = list + agents.next().getName() + "\n";
}
return list
```

Designer Help isn't all that bad, really ;)

Answer (score 0):

AS Tim wrote you need to setup that the ACL Maximum Internet name and password  is set to at least Designer otherwise this will fail.

[image: Internet maximum security level]

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good option. I would guess that it opens a number of possible security issues. In fact for my application I prefer the default access be no higher than Author, then I manipulate the authors field depending on the state of the document.