# NotesDXLExporter to export a database

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I wrote this SSJS in a button on an XPage. I want to export the current database to a dxl file.

```
var stream:NotesStream = session.createStream();
var fileName:String = "c:\\Export\\exportedDB.dxl";
dBar.info(fileName,"Start Try");
try{
    if(stream.open(fileName)){
            dBar.info("File Opened");
            stream.truncate();
            dBar.info("stream Truncate");
        exporter:NotesDxlExporter = session.createDxlExporter();
        dBar.info("Exporter Created");
        stream.writeText(exporter.exportDxl(database));
        dBar.info("Export Completed");
        stream.close();
        dBar.info("Stream Closed")
    }else{
        dBar.info("Could Not Open File");
    }
}catch(e){
    dBar.info("try failed");
}
```

I get the message "Exporter Created" in the debug toolbar but the stream.write fails and goes to the "try failed". I have manager rights to the current database so I don't see it as a rights issue. According to the examples that I have been able to locate this should work. Anyone see an issue with my code?

Comment: Can you please post the message of "e" in your catch block?

Comment: Here is the output from the dBar.info
19:10:39  (try failed) Error:'exporter' not found
19:10:39  Exporter Created
19:10:39  stream Truncate
19:10:39  File Opened
19:10:39  (Start Try) c:\Export\exportedDB.dxl
So it is failing in 
stream.writeText(exporter.exportDxl(database));
but the line above this
exporter:NotesDxlExporter = session.createDxlExporter();
seems to have been successful ie exporter was created.

Comment: Perhaps it the classic Max ACL setting
Check my answer on one of your previous questions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23019933/cycle-through-a-list-of-agents-gives-an-error/23022776#23022776

Comment: What is the purpose of that export?

Comment: You need to chain the stream to the exporter. There is a method (can't remember off my head) to set the stream to be the target of the exporter

Comment: @stwissel - I need to create a new database from an action button on an XPage, problem is that the user will not have access to a template to create the new database. Tried doing this and setting all the properties but not a pretty picture. Sven suggested using a DXL export of a template then change the stuff I need and then import the new DXL into a newly created DB. So I have now exported the DXL of the template I want to use and now I'm maaking the revisions to the the export so I can tuurn around and import it. Sven has an example of the import on his blog - thanks Sven!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "var" to the 1st exporter statement:

```
var exporter:NotesDxlExporter = session.createDxlExporter();
```

Even better: do this using Java. It makes it much easier to catch errors like this.

Comment: Yes, it does work with "var". Just tested it. It does work without ":NotesDxlExporter" and "var" too but variables should always be declared with "var" as they are otherwise defined as global.

Comment: I was laying in bed at about 3 am and the light came on (figuratively) "you did not declare the var stupid!" Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Exporting a whole database as DXL can be a little tricky. One design element with a problem and your whole export fails. So this is nothing you can 100% rely on.

I learned that lesson the hard way when I wrote DXLMagic (source is on OpenNTF). Dxl handling has gotten better with later Notes versions, but isn't "end-user ready"

I would for starters follow Per's suggestion and do this in Java. Secondly, reuse the code of DXLMagic. There I export one element after the other (and stitch it into one result) to avoid failure if one element isn't clean.

Dxl isn't very good with XPages stuff and you might be better off using an OnDisk project (code only and requires a designer on the other end)