# Error when trying to setTitle on new DB

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm working on an Archiving Application with this code in it:

```
var arcName:String = "Archives/" + aDBName + "-Backup-" + toDay + "-" + thisTime.slice(0,5);
var server:String = appDB.getServer();
var arcDB:NotesDatabase = appDB.createCopy(server, arcName);
arcDB.setTitle("This is a Test");
```

but it fails at the arcDB.setTitle - the new copy of the Database is created so there is no issue to that point.

This is from the IBM Knowledge base:

```
var db2:NotesDatabase = db.createCopy(null, "names2");
db2.setTitle("Copy of names");
```

I can't see the difference between these two pieces of code. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Fails?  is there an error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when something doesn't work with XPages that relates to database or design objects the first thing I check is the Maximum Internet Name and password Access https://stackoverflow.com/a/23045860/1187943

Or change so I do the work using sessionAsSigner or sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess

Comment: I did this in my SSJS code just as a test to see if it would work.
var appDB=sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess.getDatabase("","");
appDB.openByReplicaID(serverName,appRepID);
I then checked appDB.getCurrentAccessLevel() and it is set to 6 (Manager) which is right and now for a test I tried deleting a document but it would not delete it I have manager rights and delete document rights. So I thought from my reading that appDB should have been opened with full access rights and allow for deletion. I really don't think setting the max Internet access high is a good solution.

Comment: pulled the code apart and built it a simple test case and it works with the sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess now to see if I can get it to work in the production side.

Comment: Fredrik - finally got it working in my full code. The full Access on the DB solved the setTitle issue, but had trouble removing the documents in the document collection. Then I say my test case had docCol.removeAll(true) my full code had docCol.removeAll(). changed it to docCol.removeAll(true) in the full code and it deleted all the documents in the collection, but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the effectiveUser's access to the source database, their permissions to make a copy, and their access rights to create a NotesDatabase on the target Domino server, I'd absolutely second Fredrik's suggestion to use sessionAsSigner/WithFullAccess.

Additionally, I find it's best practice to use try/catches (helps with troubleshooting and errorHandling), object testing (.isOpen() when accessing a NotesDatabase), and returning an Object that can be read by the calling function.

Here's some example code that might help:

```
var copyNotesDatabase = function(dbName) {

    var isSuccessful = true;
    var responseMessage = "";
    try {
        //set appDB using dbName from function arguments
        var appDB = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),dbName);
        //var appDB = sessionAsSigner.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),"sourceDb.nsf");
        //var appDB = sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess.getDatabase(session.getServerName(),"sourceDb.nsf");
        if(appDB.isOpen()) {
            var arcName:String = "Archives/" + aDBName + "-Backup-" + toDay + "-" + thisTime.slice(0,5);
            var server:String = appDB.getServer();
            //arcDB will be created based on appDB permissions, ie effectiveUser, or sessionAsSigner, etc.
            var arcDB:NotesDatabase = appDB.createCopy(server, arcName);
            if(arcDB.isOpen()) {
                arcDB.setTitle("This is a Test");
                responseMessage = "Successfully copied NotesDatabase!"
            } else {
                isSuccessful = false;
                responseMessage = "Unable to open copied NotesDatabase.";
            }
        } else {
            isSuccessful = false;
            responseMessage = "Unable to open source NotesDatabase.";
        }
    } catch(e) {
        print("Error from SSJS: " + e);
        isSuccessful = false;
        responseMessage = e;
    }

    return { status : isSuccessful, message : responseMessage };
}
```

With this function, you could do something like this:

```
function makeCopy(appName) {
    var fObj = copyNotesDatabase(appName);
    if(fObj.status) {
        return "Successfully copied " + appName;
    } else {
        return fObj.message;
    }
}
```

... at the very least, using a try/catch and returning your error will at least tell you why your current code isn't working. Hope this helps!